# How to add a custom StateStore to the Kafka Streams DSL processor?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

For one of my Kafka streams apps, I need to use the features of both DSL and Processor API. My streaming app flow is

```
source -> selectKey -> filter -> aggregate (on a window) -> sink
```

After aggregation I need to send a SINGLE aggregated message to the sink. So I define my topology as below

```java
KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();
KStream<String, String> source = builder.stream(source_stream);
source.selectKey(new MyKeyValueMapper())
      .filterNot((k,v) -> k.equals("UnknownGroup"))
      .process(() -> new MyProcessor());
```

I define a custom `StateStore` and register it with my processor as below

```java
public class MyProcessor implements Processor<String, String> {

    private ProcessorContext context = null;
    Serde<HashMapStore> invSerde = Serdes.serdeFrom(invJsonSerializer, invJsonDeserializer);


    KeyValueStore<String, HashMapStore> invStore = (KeyValueStore) Stores.create("invStore")
        .withKeys(Serdes.String())
        .withValues(invSerde)
        .persistent()
        .build()
        .get();

    public MyProcessor() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.context.register(invStore, false, null); // register the store
        this.context.schedule(10 * 60 * 1000L);
    }

    @Override
    public void process(String partitionKey, String message) {
        try {
            MessageModel smb = new MessageModel(message);
            HashMapStore oldStore = invStore.get(partitionKey);
            if (oldStore == null) {
                oldStore = new HashMapStore();
            }
            oldStore.addSmb(smb);
            invStore.put(partitionKey, oldStore);
        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void punctuate(long timestamp) {
       // processes all the messages in the state store and sends single aggregate message
    }


    @Override
    public void close() {
        invStore.close();
    }
}
```

When I run the app, I get `java.lang.NullPointerException`

> Exception in thread "StreamThread-18" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueStore.flush(MeteredKeyValueStore.java:167)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager.flush(ProcessorStateManager.java:332)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.commit(StreamTask.java:252)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.commitOne(StreamThread.java:446)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.commitAll(StreamThread.java:434)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.maybeCommit(StreamThread.java:422)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:340)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:218)

Any idea what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to register you store *outside* of you processor using `StreamsBuilder` (or `KStreamBuilder` in older releases). First you create the store, than you registers it to `StreamsBuilder` (`KStreamBuilder`), and when you add the processor you provide the store name to connect the processor and the store.

```java
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

// create store
StoreBuilder storeBuilder = Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(
    Stores.persistentKeyValueStore("invStore"),
    Serdes.String(),
    invSerde));
// register store
builder.addStateStore(storeBuilder);

KStream<String, String> source = builder.stream(source_stream);
source.selectKey(new MyKeyValueMapper())
        .filterNot((k,v) -> k.equals("UnknownGroup"))
        .process(() -> new MyProcessor(), "invStore"); // connect store to processor by providing store name


// older API:

KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();

// create store
StateStoreSupplier storeSupplier = (KeyValueStore)Stores.create("invStore")
    .withKeys(Serdes.String())
    .withValues(invSerde)
    .persistent()
    .build();
// register store
builder.addStateStore(storeSupplier);

KStream<String, String> source = builder.stream(source_stream);
source.selectKey(new MyKeyValueMapper())
        .filterNot((k,v) -> k.equals("UnknownGroup"))
        .process(() -> new MyProcessor(), "invStore"); // connect store to processor by providing store name
```

Comment: It works. thanks a lot. Just curious to know, where can I use the ProcessorContext::register method?

Comment: You only need `ProcessorContext#register` if you implement your own state store (using interface `StateStore`). You would need to call `register` in `StateStore#init()`

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax If I have implemented my own state store and if I do not call register in StateStore#init() then would *processorContext.getStateStore("mystore")* work in AbstractProcessor init() method or it would return null? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need to register the store. Otherwise, it cannot be found and `getStateStore()` returns `null`.